# Possible to upload a non-file to a pre signed url?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-js

I know I can upload a file but is is possible to upload a string of text to a presigned url somehow ?

```
      const presignedLink = await dataSources.imageAPI.getPresignedLink(
        {
          image_type: "metadata",
          file_extension: "json",
        },
        user.wallet_address
      );

      const formData = new FormData();

      formData.append("key", presignedLink.fields.key);
      formData.append("bucket", presignedLink.fields.bucket);
      formData.append("X-Amz-Credential", presignedLink.fields.credential);
      formData.append("X-Amz-Algorithm", presignedLink.fields.algorithm);
      formData.append("X-Amz-Date", presignedLink.fields.date);
      formData.append("Policy", presignedLink.fields.policy);
      formData.append("X-Amz-Signature", presignedLink.fields.signature);

       
      formData.append("file",file);

      await axios({
        method: "POST",
        url: presignedLink.url,
        data: formData,
        headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
      });
```

Comment: What happened when you tried this?

Comment: the example above is the file upload which works fine. Ideally I want to avoid having to have a file to upload - and rather upload a piece of json (string) to the presigned url

Comment: I don't know which formdata library you are using, but I would assume that the `formData.append()` method accepts multiple parameter types including string, file, and buffer. Maybe you could test with `formData.append('file', JSON.stringify(myobject))`. From the [POST docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPOST.html) it looks like the 'file' field can contain "File or text content".